# How to do Shape Recognition using AForge, normalized DistanceHistograms and Neural Networks?

Tags: c#, neural-network, shapes, image-recognition, aforge

I am trying to learn Neural Networks and was trying to implement a simple Shape Recognition Alogithm in C# and AForge using Distance Histograms normalized to Values between 0 and 100.

A distance Histogram of a bone shape looks like this:

```
int[] boneHistogram = 77, 38, 30, 27, 25, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
20, 21, 20, 13, 11, 14, 13, 14, 13, 16, 16, 17, 27, 28, 34, 41, 46, 58, 100, 65, 0,
```

I computed it like described here on page 41: http://www.ai.rug.nl/~mwiering/ObjectRecognition.pdf

Now I produce a couple of those histograms. Results look like so:

```
int[]bone2Histogram = 63, 39, 27, 25, 20, 22, 20, 18, 19,
 22, 16, 21, 17, 20, 19, 20, 20, 14, 21, 16, 20, 19, 27, 44, 42, 56, 70, 100, 64, 0

int[] bone3Histogram = 62, 46, 33, 27, 24, 22, 23, 19, 22, 
20, 19, 19, 19, 18, 19, 20, 16, 19, 17, 22, 16, 25, 31, 35, 48, 52, 66, 100, 60, 0
```

and so on until I have 8 histograms.
Nect I create an input array:

```
double[][] input = new double[8][];
```

I put the histogram values from above each into a array so that input[0] corresponds to histogram 1 and input[1] to histogram 2...

**First Problem** I have: I don't really understand how to use the output values here. I know the output array has to be the same size of the input array so I create it like so:

```
double[][] output = new double[input.Length][];
```

Now does output[1].Length need to be like 30 cells or does it work with one cell? And what do I need to put into those cells? Do I need to put the same values as in Input in there or does it work with say 1 for true and 0 for false (if the corresponding input histogram is a false shape)?

I tried to apply what is descriped here [Neural Network OCR](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11285/Neural-Network-OCR)[^]but it didn't help me really

**Second Problem**
My Network then looks like this:

```
AForge.Neuro.ActivationNetwork network = new AForge.Neuro.ActivationNetwork(
            new SigmoidFunction(2),
            30, // two inputs in the network
            30, // two neurons in the first layer
            1); // one neuron in the second layer

network.Randomize();

AForge.Neuro.Learning.BackPropagationLearning teacher = new BackPropagationLearning(network);
int count = 0;
double error = 1;
// loop
do
{
error = 0;
// run epoch of learning procedure
error = teacher.RunEpoch(input, output);
//Debug.Log(error);
// check error value to see if we need to stop
count++;
if(count &gt;= 2000) break;
} while (error &gt; 0.01);
```

When I then try to compute different shapes (say comparing it with a the values of an input bone)

```
double[] boneShape = new double[] { 77, 38, 30, 27, 25, 22, 22, 22, 22, 20, 21, 20, 13, 11, 14, 13, 14, 13, 16, 16, 17, 27, 28, 34, 41, 46, 58, 100, 65, 0 };

double[] resultBone = network.Compute(boneShape);

double[] randomValues = new double[] { 14, 3, 0, 3, 40, 50, 93, 0, 34, 8, 5, 6, 10, 1, 33, 70, 80, 0, 12, 5, 3, 33, 77, 40, 3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 20 };

double[] test = network.Compute(randomValues);
```

I just get *wrong* answers depending on my settings above. What I want is a value between 0 and 1. The lower the value, the better (say 0 is 100% sure it is a equivalent shape and 1 is a totally different shape)

Are Neural Networks the right approach for such a problem? DistanceHistograms won't be too reliable but it's a start.

I really hope someone can point me in the right direction and help me getting started, because this clearly doesn't work.